# wsadmin com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: maven-2, websphere, ear, wsadmin, automated-deployment

After installing ear file through wsadmin script getting below error when starting server.
i checked within the ear file the same class present in one of the jar.

**com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**

Please suggest any solution for this issue.

Comment: Please include the full error message or stack trace (or at least the missing class), or no one will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a classpath issue. Actually i am using Maven for building the EAR. Maven has overwirte my classpath and i removed the same. Also removed maven generated maven folder inside META-INF folder of jar/ejb. addMavenDescriptor>false /addMavenDescriptor>

Thanks bkail.